# WordPress custom post type rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I'm trying to add a rule for a custom post type. By default, the URL to view post is www.mydomain.com/job/post-slug

What I'd like, is the post also accessible with the following URL:

www.mydomain.com/j/postid

I've tried this in my functions.php file and I also refresh permalinks in admin settings:

```
function rewrite_short_job_url() {

    add_rewrite_rule( '^j/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?post_type=job&id=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    flush_rewrite_rules( true );

}

add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_short_job_url' );
```

Doesn't work for me, I'm trying to understand the Rewrite API but cannot find a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure that you should be flushing rewrite rules during each request...Also, have you tested your redirect manually? What happens when you go to: `index.php?post_type=job&id=15` (or some other ID)? You may need to use `page_id`.

Comment: Ok got it, I was wrong in the redirect url, it's index.php?p=xxx that's all. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be using the following:

```
function rewrite_short_job_url() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^j/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?post_type=job&p=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_short_job_url' );
```

It's important to keep the `post_type` var, so that only job posts use that redirect.

You can view a list of WordPress query variables [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars).